# I get a vertical green line in my camera view and renders

Tags: eevee-render-engine

I'm doing some 3d scene matching tests in Blender.

I'm making some advances and getting to solve my scenes but I noticed a strange green border on the left of my movie clip I imported to match move (it's a .mov file)

I thought it was just an interface thing but now that I'm exporting my tests as render I see that the green line appears in all of them (when I have the background movie as part of the render)

The .mov file is Instagram-sized Vertical (1080 x 1350) . My scene in Blender matches the same output size. But in the final render I get the green vertical line in the left..

If I play with the camera settings and stretch the background image I can get rid of the green line but for some reason everytime I start a new VFX shot and import a .mov file I get that green line...

Any idea why I'm getting it? The original .mov file doesn't have the green line, but Blender is adding it for some reason...

It's about 4 pixels wide. I'm just magnifying it. I tried checking and unchecking all the camera settings...

[image]

[image]

Comment: if u could provide blend file it would be a great help to see whats going on

Comment: Hello Chris. Thanks for answering. I uploaded the files here: https://www.velarde.com/clients/plaza-blender.zip

Comment: i just downloaded your blend file, rendered...and...got no green line....[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oKGxf.png is it just on specific frames?

Comment: Strange... I see the green line on the left when I open the file in Blender, In Preview and in the Quicktime Player (Mac OS) ...  It lasts for the whole animation, not just a single frame

Comment: Here are some screenshots: http://velarde.com/clients/green-line.jpg

Comment: i believe you. Here is my screenshot: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UGnYw.jpg

Comment: Thanks.. ja. Unfortunately I see the green line on my end. I opened the render in Final Cut and also see it... I will have to create a new Blender file from scratch and see of this fixes the issue... Appreciate you looking at it

Comment: Maybe some other people here can help you ☺️